# Strategy to overcome caching of Axios requests?

Tags: reactjs, axios, use-effect

I've noticed that if I make a GET call to the same API endpoint twice in a row then the previous result appears to get cached.  This is causing a problem for the logic of my React component which is a multi-page Wizard.

I define my API request like this:

```
  const [{ data, isLoading, isError }, userNameDoFetch] = useFetch(
    null,
    { }
  )
```

The user can then enter a username into an input element and its existence is checked liked this:

```
  const handleBlur = (event) => {
    const propName = event.target.name;
    const propValue = event.target.value;

    if (propValue.length > 0) {
        setIsFetching(true);
         userNameDoFetch( `${API_ROOT()}account_management/users/name/${propValue}` );
      }
    }
  }
```

I then have a `useEffect` that processes the data coming back from the server.  It begins like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsFetching(false);
    ...
```

The problem is that the `useEffect` isn't called if say, the user tabs back into the Username field and then tabs out again.  This sets `isFetching` to `true`, which disables the `Next` button in my wizard, leaving the user trapped on that page.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this?